# What is the proper way to say 'good bye' in Hinduism?

Tags: culture, tradition

As we used to say `Ram Ram` or `Jay Shree Krishna` to greet when we meet someone, what is the proper **good bye** greeting in Hinduism?

I used to say 'bye, take care', but I want to change this to a proper way.

Is there any resource which mentions how to say **hello** and **bye** religiously?

As I'm a Hindu who lives in a Muslim country where they say '[Allah Hafiz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khuda_Hafiz)', I want to know something for Hindus as well.

Comment: Your question ('proper way to greet') is too broad and very subjective. There could be a 1000 ways to greet Hindu people depending on the state they reside and the language they use for conversing.

Comment: Are you asking because you would like to do a good thing or whether you are insecure about people greeting you in an Islamic way?

Comment: @AravindSuresh I am not insecure, just asked to practice it in routine.

Comment: Dhanyavad (Thank you), Punar Milamah (Let's meet again)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In our culture we never say Good bye , we say come back again , I am Gujarati we used to say come back again, In Gujarati we says "chaalo aavjo(ચલો અવોજો)" means come back again. And "Tack care is there every time". but we never say Good Bye & we also says Pranam & take Permission for go outside, from  our elders and they give us blesses.

> पुनदर्शनाय     punadarzanAya  - phrase    - good bye
>
> यानं आगतं, **आगच्छामि**   yAnaM AgataM, AgacchAmi - sent. - The bus has come, good bye.
>
> पुनः मिलामः   punaH milAmaH   - phrase    - bye

In sanskrit  we says **पुनदर्शनाय**   means come back again or see you next time for Good Bye

or also we can say

**आगच्छामि** means Good Bye

[find here](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=HK&beginning=0+&tinput=bye+&trans=Translate&direction=AU)

**hello** means simply we can says  **Pranam or Namskar**

[click here for Hello](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=hello&direction=ES&script=HK&link=yes&beginning=0)

Answer (score 1):

ram ram is used both for greeting at meeting and saying good bye in Rammargi/Ramanandi influential areas..

example: Ram Ram used as greeting at meeting:

Person1)ram ram

Person2) ram ram

Person1) Kaise hain?

---

example2: Ram Ram used as bye bye/good bye:

Person1) chaltaa hoon. Ram Ram

Person2) Ram Ram.

---

In Gujarat, "Jai shri krishna" is used in many areas **for both greetings at meeting and bye bye/goodbye.**

In some regions like around Mathura and Vrindavan , "radhe radhe" used **for both greeting at meeting and bye bye**

In some regions, "jai shri ram","hari bol","jai mahakal","jai mata di" is also used **for both** .

Answer (score 0):

Respectfully the head is tilted down a little & palms folded (in *Namaskara* position), one asks ***"Aagya"***. The other person performs the same gesture without speaking anything. The elderly person also may raise his hand(s) with palm facing towards the seeker, occasionally followed by a relevant blessing.

Instead of saying "Good Bye", it's like asking permission to go away. The English equivalent is *"Kindly allow me to leave"*.
This is a famous way observed also in popular cultures like TV shows & movies.